# preg match on specific amount of decimal characters

Tags: php, preg-match

How to match for a specific amount of decimal characters?

```
preg_match('/([0-9]{15,16})[^0-9]/', $input, $matches))
```

## examples

```
no. 05485845150270008225169 => NO MATCH!
no. 50270008225169 => NO MATCH!
FI 150270008225169 => MATCH!
FI 5150270008225169 => MATCH!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add lookarounds to the pattern to match no more than 16 digits:

```
(?<!\d)\d{15,16}(?!\d)
```

https://regex101.com/r/aO0tA5/1

Comment: Curious why not word boundaries, `\b`, instead of lookarounds?

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: this is an option too, depends on what the OP wants to do with `xyz123123123`.